# VARCHAR vs DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, datatypes

What is the reason for using VARCHAR datatype on a column storing values in date and time `2020-01-01 11:04:37` instead of using `DATETIME` datatype in SQL database table?

Comment: The only possible reason may be necessity to store incorrect datetime - for example, zero as day number, or "anyvalue" placeholder in month...

Comment: @Akina The only possible? I can think of other reasons.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I do not see any another reason for to store dates in string type field in static tables. If you may find another cases, I would like you to describe them.

Comment: @Akina As we mentioned earlier, when importing data from untrusted sources. What about different calendar systems?

Comment: @Colin'tHart *when importing data from untrusted sources* The case mentioned earlier tells about temporary table, not static one. *different calendar systems* can be uniquely converted to datetime and back (and should while processing, especially while compare with another calendar system dates) - consider such converting as normalization.

Comment: @Akina The fact remains that as a DBA you need to be pedantic, and you used the word "only".

Comment: @Colin'tHart Sorry, but comments are editable for 4 mins only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reason. This is **wrong** design, which leads to problems when you need to handle some date based filters or manipulation.

For storing date and time information, `datetime` data type should be ued ALWAYS.

Dealing with dates as string (`varchar`s) leads to lot of casting, which is bad e.g. for performance.

So, answering once again your question: there's no reason at all for such ddesign.

To complete answer (from comments):

> Never say never. When importing data from eg CSV or plain text files, it's often helpful to be able to import the entire file without any rejects and then perform a second step to convert data from the imported table to the final destination table. In these cases I will import all data into text fields, while the final destination table will have proper data types.

**BUT** this should be just intermediate step, not the way date would be stored.

Answer (score 2):

Possibilites:

- Honest mistake?
- Excessive haste?
- Plain ignorance?
- Sheer laziness?
- Rank stupidity?

IMHO, there are *no* Good Reasons for storing "date" values in anything other than **Date** Data Types.

You will *always*, at some point, wind up wanting to do **Date** "things" with these values and having them stored in the wrong Data Type (or, worse still, the wrong "format") just makes that *so* much more difficult (or, at the very least, so much *slower*).

As a famous engineer once said "... the right tool for the right job!"